# Cant move to right and left while in d flex

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I have a problem, as you can see in the picture below, I want 1 to be in the left and 2 to be in the right. What's wrong with my code?

[image]

```
<div className="mt-5 mx-5 py-3 shadow bg-white">
  <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div style={{ float: "left", display: "flex" }}>
      <div className="p-2">1</div>
    </div>
    <div className="p-2 me-4">Popular Products</div>
    <div className="p-2">Low Prive</div>
    <div className="p-2 ms-4">High Price</div>
    <div style={{ float: "right", display: "flex" }}>
      <div className="p-2">2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
[image]
you need to use justify-content-between

```
    <div className="mt-5 mx-5 py-3 shadow bg-white">
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
                <div>
                    <div className="p-2">1</div>
                </div>

                <div className="d-flex justify-content-center w-100">
                    <div className="p-2 me-4">Popular Products</div>
                    <div className="p-2">Low Prive</div>
                    <div className="p-2 ms-4">High Price</div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <div className="p-2">2</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: thanks, how to put actual picture instead of links?

Comment: you can remove w-100 in <div className="d-flex justify-content-center w-100">

Comment: I added another answer for teach you add a picture

Comment: I edited my answer and I showed you.good luck

Comment: Hi I really wanna ask related to this but is it okay? Its different question but same code

Comment: sure do it ....

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxpoj.png I want the left and right text be select like this and the middle tabs like this.

Comment: if you make a codesandbox it is very helpfull

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-mendeleev-e42et?file=/src/App.js here it is hehe ......

Comment: I saw that but I don't find any solution with reactstrap

Comment: if you want to do that any way you need to make tabs

Comment: ya can can you help me with that?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-platform-mg9qt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: please check it

Comment: and if my answer is right don't forget to give me a green check pleas

Comment: Oh ya I see about that tabs. How about dropdowns? I want it custom like https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxpoj.png

Comment: you just need to put your dropdown there.i put a simple dropdown in codesand box

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-platform-mg9qt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hi, can you also give upvote also? :D

Comment: I did it ......